# Working with digital signatures in Go

Tags: go, rsa, digital-signature

I would like to use signatures for a program that I am writing in Go, but I can't figure out the documentation, which is [here](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/). In particular, I would like to use the `SignPKCS1v15` and `VerifyPKCS1v15` functions, but I'm not sure exactly what I have to pass as arguments. I would greatly benefit from some example code of these two functions. Thanks.

Note: The message that I would like to send is a struct that I defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [`src\pkg\crypto\rsa\pkcs1v15_test.go`](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/crypto/rsa/pkcs1v15_test.go?name=go1) file in the Go source tree should be a good start.

**An update** striving provide more context… Go source contains many tests for the code in its standard library (and the `crypto/rsa` package is a part of it), so whenever you have no idea how to *use* a standard package (or, actually, any other Go package), a good place to start is to look at the tests involving that package as testing code naturally *uses* the package! Tests are kept in files ending in `_test.go`, usually have meaningful names and are located in the same directories actual code implementing a particular package is kept.

So in your particular case you could do this:

1. Download the Go source package of the version matching your compiler (what `go version` shows) and unpack it somewhere.
2. Navigate to the directory matching the package of interest.  Code for standard Go packages is located in the "pkg" directory under the "src" top-level directory, so if you're interested in the `crypto/rsa` package, you need the `src/pkg/crypto/rsa` directory.

Comment: what is the best way to locate this file? I tried 'which go', but that returned nothing.

Comment: @nemo linkified that for you, @abw333, to point to the copy of that file available through the browser of the Go code repository, so just click the link. But actually I was referring to the Go source tree implying you could just download the Go *source* tarball and unwrap it.  I should also add that the Windows build of Go comes with full Go source and I beleive installing a Go compiler on Debian also pulls the relevant Go sources.  So I'd just search your filesystem for a file named `pkcs1v15_test.go`.

Comment: @abw333, I've updated my post to provide some hands-holding and better outline the general idea of studying testing code.